# Is there any way to connect shopware 6 with TYPO3

Tags: typo3, shopware

I want to connect shopware6 with TYPO3.Tried the plugin `shopware-typo3-connector` but it is not compatible with shopware6. Is there any other possible way?

Comment: Build your own connector.

Comment: Did you try to get in touch with the plugin author to get the connector updated? Sponsoring code and/or money may help.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not find a plugin the community store you can look out for a partner from [the agency listing](https://www.shopware.com/en/partner/agencies/) and reach out to a partner claiming to have TYPO3 experience. If you are not happy with the search of an agency you really want to build it on your own. I personally do not find it difficult to do but this often depends on the cases of data you want to connect. You likely want to look into the API of Shopware 6. You can find in the [Shopware docs](https://docs.shopware.com/en) links to different APIs and how to use them. Likely you want to use the [Admin API](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/) or write an app for Shopware 6. They have several guides (written and visual) in their docs. Depending on any follow up question you can post a new one here with the Shopware-6 tag.